# How can I animate a text fly-in in a carousel using twitter bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, animation, twitter-bootstrap

Recently I saw this feature on http://hondajet.honda.com/ - where when the carousel slides left, a text block animates/flies in from the top. Got the carousel to work fine but haven't had much success with the text animation.

How can I get this text fly-in feature?  I want to trigger the text animation when the carousel  ***slide*** event is triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not exactly what you're looking for, but it'll help point the way:

http://jsfiddle.net/coltrane/Pn2UB/

That example makes heavy use of jQuery, but doesn't have anything to do with twitter bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks a lot - this is very helpful. Will try to get it working with Bootstraps carousel and post the results back.